# How to load data into a select input using vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a file called PostJobCreate.vue where an Employer can create a new job post.
I also have a table called locations with address columns and location_name column.
An employer can have many locations.
I'm trying to load the employers Locations into a select field so that when they create a new Job Post, they know what Location it is for.

I'm loading all of the employers locations in `locations: []`.

so I could get a column like this `this.locations.location_name`.

How can I load all of the location_name into a select field, so that a User can select the location the Job Post is for?

This is what I have so far very basic:

```
<b-form-group label="Location Name" label-for="location_name">
    <b-form-select
        v-model="locations.location_name"
        :options=""
        id="location_name"
        size="sm"
    >
    </b-form-select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.location_name">{{ errors.location_name[0] }}</div>
</b-form-group>
```

I want to load the location_name field for every record in the table, inside the `:options`. I might need a v-for, but I'm not sure what to do next.

PostJobCreate.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Post a Job</h3>
                <form class="forms-sample" v-on:submit.prevent="createJobPosts">

                    <b-form-group
                        label="Employment Type"
                        label-for="employment-type"
                    >
                        <b-form-radio-group
                            id="employment-type"
                            v-model="jobPostsData.employment_type"
                            :options="jobPostsData.optionsTwo"
                            name="employment-type"
                        >
                        </b-form-radio-group>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.employment_type">{{ errors.employment_type[0] }}</div>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-form-group label="Job Title" label-for="job_title">
                        <b-form-select
                            v-model="jobPostsData.job_title"
                            :options="jobPostsData.optionsThree"
                            id="job_title"
                            placeholder="Enter job title"
                        >
                        </b-form-select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.job_title">{{ errors.job_title[0] }}</div>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-form-group label="Job Description" label-for="job_description">
                        <b-form-textarea
                            v-model="jobPostsData.job_description"
                            id="job_description"
                            placeholder="Enter job description"
                            :rows="10"
                            :max-rows="12"
                            class="mb-2"
                        ></b-form-textarea>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.job_description">{{ errors.job_description[0] }}</div>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-form-group label="Salary Range" label-for="salary">
                        <b-form-select
                            v-model="jobPostsData.salary"
                            :options="jobPostsData.options"
                            id="salary"
                            size="sm"
                        >
                        </b-form-select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.salary">{{ errors.salary[0] }}</div>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-form-group label="Location Name" label-for="location_name">
                        <b-form-select
                            v-model="locations.location_name"
                            :options=""
                            id="location_name"
                            size="sm"
                        >
                        </b-form-select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.location_name">{{ errors.location_name[0] }}</div>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-row>
                        <b-col class="text-left">
                            <b-button type="submit" variant="success" class="mr-2"
                            ><i class="mdi mdi-check-circle"></i> Save</b-button
                            >
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import * as employerService from '../../../services/employer_service.js';
    import * as employerLocationService from '../../../services/employer_location_service.js';

    export default {
        name: "postJobCreate",

        data() {
            return {
                locations: [],

                jobPostsData: {
                    job_title: null,
                    optionsThree: [
                        { value: null, text: 'Please select an option' },
                        { value: 'Budtender/Retail', text: 'Budtender/Retail' },
                        { value: 'Delivery/Courier', text: 'Delivery/Courier' },
                        { value: 'Security', text: 'Security' },
                        { value: 'Grower/Horticulturalist', text: 'Grower/Horticulturalist'},
                        { value: 'Master Grower', text: 'Master Grower'},
                        { value: 'Extraction', text: 'Extraction'},
                        { value: 'Chemist', text: 'Chemist'},
                        { value: 'Trimmer', text: 'Trimmer'},
                        { value: 'Packagers', text: 'Packagers'},
                        { value: 'Manufacturing', text: 'Manufacturing'},
                        { value: 'Edible Production', text: 'Edible Production'},
                        { value: 'Sales', text: 'Sales'},
                        { value: 'Marketing', text: 'Marketing'},
                        { value: 'Management', text: 'Management'},
                        { value: 'Executive Level', text: 'Executive Level'},
                        { value: 'Other', text: 'Other'},
                    ],
                    job_description: '',
                    employment_type: 'Freelance',
                    optionsTwo: [
                        { value: "Freelance", text: "Freelance", },
                        { value: "Full Time", text: "Full Time", },
                        { value: "Internship", text: "Internship", },
                        { value: "Part Time", text: "Part Time", },
                    ],
                    salary: '40,000 and under',
                    options: [
                        { value: '40,000 and under', text: '40,000 and under' },
                        { value: '40,000-50,000', text: '$40,000-50,000' },
                        { value: '50,000-60,000', text: '$50,000-60,000' },
                        { value: '60,000-70,000', text: '$60,000-70,000' },
                        { value: '70,000-80,000', text: '$70,000-80,000' },
                        { value: '80,000-90,000', text: '$80,000-90,000' },
                        { value: '90,000-100,000', text: '$90,000-100,000' },
                        { value: '100,000-150,000', text: '$100,000-150,000' },
                        { value: '150,000-200,000', text: '$150,000-200,000' },
                        { value: '200,000-250,000', text: '$200,000-250,000' },
                        { value: '250,000-300,000', text: '$250,000-300,000' },
                        { value: '300,000-350,000', text: '$300,000-350,000' },
                        { value: '350,000-400,000', text: '$350,000-400,000' },
                        { value: '400,000-450,000', text: '$400,000-450,000' },
                        { value: '450,000-500,000', text: '$450,000-500,000' },
                        { value: '500,000-1,000,000', text: '$500,000-1,000,000' },
                        { value: '1,000,000+', text: '1,000,000+' }
                    ],
                },

                errors: {}

            };
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loadLocations();
        },

        methods: {
            createJobPosts: async function() {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('job_title', this.jobPostsData.job_title);
                formData.append('job_description', this.jobPostsData.job_description);
                formData.append('employment_type', this.jobPostsData.employment_type);
                formData.append('salary', this.jobPostsData.salary);
                formData.append('location_name', this.locations.location_name);

                try {
                    const response = await employerService.createJobPosts(formData);
                    this.$router.push('/post-a-job');
                    this.$toast.success("Job Post created Successfully!");
                } catch (error) {
                    switch (error.response.status) {
                        case 422:
                            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                            break;
                        default:
                            this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please try again!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },

            loadLocations: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await employerLocationService.loadLocations();
                    this.locations = response.data.locations.data;

                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error('Some error occurred, please refresh!');
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [Change the option field names](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#changing-the-option-field-names) as follows :

```
    <b-form-select
     v-model="selectedLocation"
      :options="locations"
      id="location_name"
      size="sm"
      value-field="location_name"
      text-field="location_name"
    >
...
```

`selectedLocation` should be defined in data as follows :

```
    data() {
        return {
            locations: [],
            selectedLocation:null
   . ..
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Is there a way to add a default value for the input? For example: "Select your Location"? So that would be the first thing they see?